# Find the Domain of a Rational Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the domain of
$$ \frac{\frac{3x+3}{2x-3}+1}{\frac{3x+3}{2x-3}-3}. $$

I've tried saying that there is no way that $x=4$. Is there another number that won't work?

Comment: yes x=3/2 for example

Comment: I feel like a *just* answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419472/what-is-the-domain-of-frac25x8)...  The same reasoning applies:  determine where the denominators are zero, then exclude those values.

Comment: You have a high questioning rate : 3 questions / 3 hours. Take time for breathing...

Comment: Megan, slow down.  In the span of three hours, you've posted three questions, everyone of them about the domain of a function.  Please don't mistaken this site as a do-my-home-work-for-me site.

Answer (score 2):

Write $f(x) = \frac{3x+3}{2x-3} +1$ and $g(x)=\frac{3x+3}{2x-3}-3$ you're asking what is the domain of $\frac{f}{g}$, so $x$ is in the domain of $\frac{f}{g}$ if and only if $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and $g$, and $g(x)\not = 0$.

The domain of $f,g$ is $x\not = 3/2$. Let's find $x\not = 3/2$ for which $g(x)=0$

$$\frac{3x+3}{2x-3}-3 = 0\rightarrow x=4$$

It follows that the domain of $\frac{f}{g}$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x\not = 3/2,4$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\dfrac{\dfrac{3x+3}{\boxed{2x-3}}+1}{\boxed{\dfrac{3x+3}{\boxed{2x-3}}-3}}$

We can't divide by $0$

$\mathcal{D}_f=\bigg\{x\in \mathbb{R}\,|\quad2x-3\ne0 \;\land \;\dfrac{3x+3}{2x-3}-3\ne0\bigg\}$

It remains to solve 2 equations