# Finding domains of functions such as $y = \sqrt{25-5^x}$, $y = e^{\arcsin x}$, $y = \cos^{-1}\left(e^{3x}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am having difficulty finding the domains of some functions

$$y = \sqrt{25-5^x}$$

With this one I am confused on how to handle the $5^x$ part when I set

$$25-5^x \geq 0$$

Also, these two other functions:
$$y = e^{\arcsin x}$$
$$y = \cos^{-1}\left(e^{3x}\right)$$
With these, I am also confused about how to handle solving the domains.

I would really appreciate it if someone can share general principles on how to approach finding these domains and then show how they can be applied.

Comment: Some of my comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2419490/) are relevant to your question.

Comment: For composition of functions like $g(f(x))$, you need to ensure that the image of $f$ is compatible with the domain of $g$.

Comment: If you have a composite function $f(g(x))$ then you're looking for values of $x$ (from the domain of $g$) for which $ g(x) \in \text{Domain}(f)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **"General method"** to solve these type of problems is to start by thinking simpler cases of the same problem. For example; if the problem is to find the domain of  $\sqrt{ax + b^2x - c}$, think at the most basic level: What determines the square root function to be defined? Of couse $(ax + b^2x - c)$. Similarly, think about the inverse trig. functions, $\arcsin(...)$ and $\arccos(...)$, you need to check for what values of $(...)$ are the functions actually defined.

***Let me help you in solving these problems!***

---

**Problem 1:**
$$y = \sqrt{25 - 5^x} \implies 25 - 5^x \ge 0\implies25  \ge 5^x$$
Taking log both sides,
$$  \log(25)  \ge  \log(5^x) \implies \log(5^2) \ge \log(5^x)\implies2 \ge x.$$

Thus domain is all real numbers less than or equal to $2$.

---

**Problem 2:**

$$y = e^{\arcsin(x)}$$
$e^{(...)}$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ i.e. reals. You just need to take care of the domain of arc sine function. It is well known that arcsine function is defined only in $[-1, 1]$ and is undefined elsewhere.

Thus domain is all real numbers in the interval $[-1,  1]$.

---

**Problem 3:**
$$y = \arccos(e^{3x})$$

This is similar to the above problem. For the $\arccos(...)$ function to be defined, $(...)$ must lie in the interval $[-1, 1]$ because arc cosine function is undefined elsewhere.

Thus we have,
$$ - 1\le e^{3x} \le 1$$

The exponential function is always $+ve$, so the above inequality changes to,
$$e^{3x} \le 1$$ this is true $\forall \ x\ \in \ (-\infty, 0]$ and so is the domain of the function.

---

The best way to verify our solution is [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f04ug9x1u9).

Answer (score 3):

For the first example, we want to find all $x$ such that
$$25-5^x \geq 0 \implies 25 \geq 5^x.$$
You know that $5^2 = 25$.  Now, because the exponential function $5^x$ increases as $x$ increases, you know that $x \leq 2$.

For the other examples, you want to always start with the outermost function.

For $\cos^{-1}(x)$, the domain is $[-1,1]$.  That tells us that $0 \leq e^{3x} \leq 1$ (since the exponential is always nonnegative), which means that $-\infty < x < ?$ (to be evaluated).

Now, focus on $e^{3x} \leq 1$ and take log of both sides:
$$3x \leq \ln(1) = 0 \implies x \le 0.$$
So, the domain for the third example is $-\infty < x \leq 0.$

Comment: The domain of $\cos^{-1}$ is $[-1,1]$

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually, the exponential is always positive.

Comment: @jjagmath and hence it is always $≥0$ (non-negative).

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted. Looks like a reasonable answer to me.